# Add model.obj to three.MESH

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am new to three.js and I am making an augmented reality app on web to show plates of food. So far I have managed to show a cube. The problem raised when I tried to show a model.obj instead of geomerty and material in mesh. Can anyone please help me on how to put a model.obj in THREE.MESH since I cannot do it. Below is my code.

```
 function createContainer() {
    var model = new THREE.Object3D();
    model.matrixAutoUpdate = false;
    return model;
}

function createMarkerMesh(color) {
       manager = new THREE.LoadingManager();
     manager.onProgress = function (item, loaded, total) {

        console.log(item, loaded, total);

    };
     var texture = new THREE.Texture();
     var loader = new THREE.ImageLoader(manager);
     loader.load(texturePath, function (image) {

      texture.image = image;
      texture.needsUpdate = true;
      texture.transparent = true;

    });

    var loader = new THREE.OBJLoader(manager);
    return loader.load(objectPath, function (object) {

        object.traverse(function (child) {

            if (child instanceof THREE.Mesh) {

                child.material.map = texture;
                child.material.transparent = true;

            }

        });
        object.position.z = -50; 

        return object;
    });

   // var geometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry( 100,100,100 );
   //var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( {color:color, side:THREE.DoubleSide } );
    var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( object.geometry, object.material);                      
    mesh.position.z = -50;

   return mesh;
}



function createMarkerObject(params) {
 //return   createMarkerMesh(params.color);
 var modelContainer = createContainer();
 var modelMesh = createMarkerMesh(params.color);
 console.log(modelMesh);
 modelContainer.add( modelMesh);

    function transform(matrix) {
        modelContainer.transformFromArray( matrix );
    }

    return {
        transform: transform,
        model: modelContainer
    }
  return {
    createMarkerObject:createMarkerObject
}

}
```

The code in function Create MArker MEsh is were the cube was created and worked fine now I have commented those parts and tried to show the object but nothing is happening please help me.

Comment: so what exactly is not going right? please elaborate  the problem/or if you can show a demo.

Comment: The problem is the object.geometry and the pbject.materail is being undefined

Comment: yes that is because the `OBJloader` function returns an `object3D` type of object, which in turn contains all the meshes(which have the materials and geometries) .just try using `console.log(object)` to see it for your self

Comment: yes but how can i placeit in THREE.MESH ? please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I have found an answer for this problem and here I am going to explain what the problem was with the above code. Hope that this will help.

The problem was that the createMarkerObject was being called before the mesh was created so the object3D container was being filled with an empty mesh. To arrange this I have declared the modelContainer as a global variable and inserted it in the createMarkerMesh function. In the createMarkerObject I have made an if condition so that it checks if the modelContainer is full before adding it to the object3D container. Below is the updated code.

```
//Loads the model and texture and creates a mesh returns mesh with model
   function createMarkerMesh() {
       manager = new THREE.LoadingManager();
       manager.onProgress = function (item, loaded, total) {
       console.log(item, loaded, total);
    };
    var texture = new THREE.Texture();
    var loader = new THREE.ImageLoader(manager);
    loader.load(texturePath, function (image) {

    texture.image = image;
    texture.needsUpdate = true;
    texture.transparent = true;

    });
    var tmpMesh, mesh;
    var loader = new THREE.OBJLoader(manager);
    loader.load(objectPath, function (object) {
    tmpMesh = object; //store the object in a variable
    object.traverse(function (child) {
    if (child instanceof THREE.Mesh) {
        child.material.map = texture;
    child.material.transparent = true;
    }
    });

    mesh = new THREE.Mesh( tmpMesh.children[0].geometry, tmpMesh.children[0].material);
    mesh.position.z = -10;
    mesh.scale.set( 3, 3, 0 );
    console.log(mesh);
    modelContainer.add( mesh);
    console.log(modelContainer);
    //return mesh;

      });

      } 



//Creates the position of the object on the marker
 function createMarkerObject() {
 modelContainer = createContainer();
 var modelMesh = createMarkerMesh();
 //console.log(modelMesh);
 if(modelMesh){
 modelContainer.add( modelMesh);
 }
    function transform(matrix) {
     modelContainer.transformFromArray( matrix );
                }

    return {
        transform: transform,
        model: modelContainer
    }
  return {
    createMarkerObject:createMarkerObject
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this change in your code... let me know if any problem raise..

```
function createMarkerMesh(color) {
   manager = new THREE.LoadingManager();
   manager.onProgress = function (item, loaded, total) {
   console.log(item, loaded, total);
 };
 var texture = new THREE.Texture();
 var loader = new THREE.ImageLoader(manager);
 loader.load(texturePath, function (image) {

  texture.image = image;
  texture.needsUpdate = true;
  texture.transparent = true;

});
var tmpMesh;
var loader = new THREE.OBJLoader(manager);
loader.load(objectPath, function (object) {
var group = new THREE.Object3D()
object.traverse(function (child) {
    if (child instanceof THREE.Mesh) {
        child.material.map = texture;
    child.material.transparent = true;
        //here in child the geometry and material are available
        var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( child.geometry, child.material);
        //mesh.position.z = -50;
        group.add(mesh);
    }
});
group.position.z = -50;
scene.add(group);//return group;
});
}
```

Comment: I have added a return before loader.load since it was giving me an error of cannot access geometry of undefined and this was solved. But now it is giving me and error undefined, i think it is not fiinding the geomerty and matrerial of the object

Comment: did you try.... `var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( tmpMesh.children[0].geometry, tmpMesh.children[0].material);
mesh.position.z = -50;
return mesh;'`

Comment: Still keeps getting undefined

Comment: can you create the mesh inside the `loader.load(url,function(obj){...do your stuff... var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( tmpMesh.children[0].geometry, tmpMesh.children[0].material); mesh.position.z = -50; return object;});`.. still you face problems.. share your code in fiddle might help..

Comment: it is till not working the problem is that the mesh no longer being null but the modelmesh is still keep getting undefined. The link to jsfiddle is http://jsfiddle.net/michsult/6J5J6/

Comment: in three.js example webgl_loader_obj.html.. please make changes as shown below in line no:95 to 112.. so you can get some idea on the mesh creation.. `var loader = new THREE.OBJLoader( manager );    loader.load( 'obj/male02/male02.obj', function ( object ) {    var group = new THREE.Object3D();     object.traverse( function ( child ) {
if ( child instanceof THREE.Mesh ) {
child.material.map = texture;       mesh = new THREE.Mesh( child.geometry, child.material );
group.add(mesh);
}
} );
group.position.y = -80;
scene.add(group);
} );` check above edited answer also..

Comment: You solution didn`t work but i have managed to do it thanks anyways

Comment: Wat problem u faced this time.... U should create mesh as i mention above else you wont get all part of the mesh... Try your solution and my answer in the example webgl_loader_obj.html